# Python stack and queue classes, implemented using lists

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented, stack, queue

I have made a stack and queue implementation with OOP in Python (sorry for variable names) . It is made from scratch. I just watched a video how these two things work. I am still trying to improve in OOP so I would be thankful for every advice. Two things which bother me the most are using `que` and `sta` in the beginning and whether it is okay to just use already implemented functions in Python such as `.pop()` .

**QUEUE**

```
que = []

class Queue:
    def __init__(self,queue):
        self.queue = queue

    def push(self,item):
        print ("PUSH",item)

        if len(self.queue)!=0:
            self.queue.append(0)
            for i in range(len(self.queue)-1,0,-1): ## replacing elements 
                self.queue[i] = self.queue[i-1]
            self.queue[0] = item

        else:
            self.queue.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        print ("POP",self.queue[-1])

        if len(self.queue)!=0:
            self.queue.pop()
        else:
            raise ValueError('Cant pop from empty queue.')

    def __str__(self):
        return (str(self.queue))

## creating QUEUE  
que = Queue(que)
que.push(5)
print (que)
que.push(6)
print (que)
que.push(7)
print (que)
que.pop()
print (que)
```

**STACK**

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self,stack):
        self.stack = stack

    def push(self,item):
        print ("PUSH",item)

        if len(self.stack)!=0:
            self.stack.append(0)
            for i in range(len(self.stack)-1,0,-1):
                self.stack[i] = self.stack[i-1]
            self.stack[0] = item

        else:
            self.stack.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        print ("POP",self.stack[0])

        if len(self.stack)!=0:
            self.stack.pop(0)
        else:
            raise ValueError('Cant pop from empty stack.')

    def __str__(self):
        return (str(self.stack))
## creating STACK
stac = Stack(sta)
stac.push(5)
print(stac)
stac.push(7)
print(stac)
stac.push(2)
print(stac)
stac.pop()
print(stac)
```

Comment: What is `que`? What is `sta`? As presented, the code doesn't run.

Comment: @vnp `que` is defined in the first statement. Assuming that `sta` is similarly defined, this code is reviewable.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things to mention.

At first, it might be a good idea to initialize both `Queue` and `Stack` with empty lists by default:

```
def __init__(self, queue=None):
    self.queue = queue or []    # if queue is given, it overrides the default
```

Next, it doesn't make sense to write something like `if len(self.queue)!=0` since it is equivalent to `if self.queue` (empty list is `False` when it's casted to bool). You can go even further and introduce the `property` called `size` using the built-in decorator:

```
@property
def size(self):
    return len(self.queue)
```

Now it can be accessed by `self.size` without a function call.

Comment: or you can implement `__len__` instead of `size`… now your container behave like any other as regard to the `len()` builtin.

Answer (score 4):

Adopting an existing list is generally a bad idea.  Code outside of the `Queue` and `Stack` classes could still hold a reference to the list and manipulate it behind your back.  The simplest remedy is to always construct the object as an empty data structure.

In your `Stack`, adding and removing items at the front of a list (at index 0) gives the worst performance, since every existing element needs to be shifted over.  This work is clearly visible in your `.push()`, but less obviously, `self.stack.pop(0)` also does that kind of work.  For efficiency, you should append and truncate items at the end of the list instead.